# Configure Ocelot API gateway with Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, ocelot

Trying to add Auth to an Ocelot API Gateway I ran into some issue. Project is running .netcore 3.1 using Microsoft.Identity.Web as this should be the new common ground for MS auth.

Azure B2C is setup and I'm able to retrieve auth code and bearer tokens based on the auth code.

Then tried the tokens with the API, but Ocelot rejects all the time.

I found some different config for AzureAD and AzureAdB2C combined with Ocelot, but not sure the are up2date.

As far as I can see this call should be enough to configure

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
```

The docs on combining Ocelot and Azure B2C does not seems to be updated very recently. All help is appreciated, thanks.